# CSS table-cell height equal to img height

Tags: html, css

I have CSS-table (display: table) > with inner divs (display: table-cell) > with inner imgs.

Table-cells widths are equal to imgs' width, but the problem is table-cells' heights are not! It's adding  some extra (4 or 5) px. So if my img is 100px (height), then table-cell is 104px.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sergeyfomin/Lyv5qc3b/1/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="table">
  <div class="table-cell"><img src="http://www.ddwcolor.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/Blue-square1.jpg" alt=""></div>
  <div class="table-cell"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3d/Cyan-square.png" alt=""></div>
  <div class="table-cell"><img src="http://www.ddwcolor.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/Blue-square1.jpg" alt=""></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.table {
  display: table;
}

.table-cell {
  display: table-cell;
  background: black;
}
```

Please let me know why's this happening and how to solve it?

Comment: Even if you add JSFiddle link, always add your code in question.

Comment: okay, but what if code is too long, Damian?

Comment: You should still add it. The reason is that someone might have similar problem, JSFiddle link can expire and person won't know your starting point. That's why you should always add code (or at least essential part of code), which is problematic.

Comment: Okay, thank you Damian, ll do it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a display property to your images.

```css
.table {
  display: table;
}
.table-cell {
  display: table-cell;
  background: black;
}
img {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="table-cell">
    <img src="http://www.ddwcolor.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/Blue-square1.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="table-cell">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3d/Cyan-square.png" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="table-cell">
    <img src="http://www.ddwcolor.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/Blue-square1.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Aaron, I guess the answer to "why" lies in img being an inline element, right?:)